# Google Forms Submission Limit & Rate Limit

Tags: javascript, jsonp, google-docs, google-forms

I was thinking about using forms + spreadsheet to collect user data in a serverless app. I'm not displaying the form, but using a JSONP call as described here: [Mock backend server (Google Forms) in AngurJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101145/mock-backend-server-google-forms-in-angurjs)

3 problems I'm worried about (feel free to point out more worries):

1. is this usage of google forms + spreadsheets against google's policy in any way?
2. is there a submission limit?
3. is there a rate limit? if so, can I guard against it?